# Karate mock API: /__admin/stop endpoint not stopping mock service (standalone jar v1.3.0)

Tags: karate

I am running a mock service using the karate standalone jar version 1.3.0.

Mocking is working fine.

However, when I make a GET request to the /__admin/stop endpoint, the process registers that the endpoint has been called, closes the listen port, but does not stop.

Execution output and scripts...

on startup:

```
java -jar /opt/karate/karate.jar -m src/test/java/mocks/fs/john.feature -p 80
16:17:16.671 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - Karate version: 1.3.0
16:17:17.315 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - mock server initialized: src/test/java/mocks/fs/john.feature
16:17:17.425 [main]  DEBUG com.intuit.karate.http.HttpServer - server started: aad-9mpcfg3:65080
```

netstat on listen socket:

```
netstat -na | grep 65080
tcp6       0      0 :::65080                :::*                    LISTEN
```

submission of curl commands:

```
curl -v http://localhost:65080/john/transactionservice/ping

*   Trying 127.0.0.1:65080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 65080 (#0)
> GET /john/transactionservice/ping HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:65080
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 49
< server: Armeria/1.18.0
< date: Mon, 28 Nov 2022 16:19:37 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"message":"this is the JOHN TransactionService"}

curl -v http://localhost:65080/__admin/stop

*   Trying 127.0.0.1:65080...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 65080 (#0)
> GET /__admin/stop HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:65080
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
< content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 12
< server: Armeria/1.18.0
< date: Mon, 28 Nov 2022 16:19:54 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

output after curl commands:

```
java -jar /opt/karate/karate.jar -m src/test/java/mocks/fs/john.feature -p 80
16:17:16.671 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - Karate version: 1.3.0
16:17:17.315 [main]  INFO  com.intuit.karate - mock server initialized: src/test/java/mocks/fs/john.feature
16:17:17.425 [main]  DEBUG com.intuit.karate.http.HttpServer - server started: aad-9mpcfg3:65080
16:19:37.312 [armeria-common-worker-epoll-2-1]  DEBUG com.intuit.karate - scenario matched at line 3: pathMatches('john/transactionservice/ping') && methodIs('get')
16:19:54.603 [armeria-common-worker-epoll-2-2]  DEBUG com.intuit.karate.http.HttpServer - received command to stop server: /__admin/stop
```

At this point, `netstat` on listen port shows socket is closed, but the process continues to run:

```
ps -ef | grep karate
matt     15070 15069  1 16:17 pts/3    00:00:03 java -jar karate-1.3.0.jar -m src/test/java/mocks/fs/john.feature -p 65080
```

This is the test mock that I am using (src/test/java/mocks/fs/john.feature):

```
Feature: JOHN TransactionService mock

Scenario: pathMatches('john/transactionservice/ping') && methodIs('get')
    * def response = {}
    * set response.message = 'this is the JOHN TransactionService'
    * def responseStatus = 200
```

Question:

Is there something else I should be doing to make the mock process stop? I think I'm following the guidance at https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#stopping

Thank you in anticipation of responses.

Comment: sounds very much like a bug. do consider contributing a PR